# Display only if Item with 3 or more result

Tags: sql-server

I need your help. I need to display only the item with 3 or more result upon in query

This SQL statement is to get only the type of each item.

```
select INUMBR as ITEM, IUPC as BARCODE, IUPCCD as Type
from [DWSTAGE].[INVUPC] 
where iupccd = 'X'
order by INUMBR
```

This is my query result:

```
ITEM          | BARCODE             | TYPE  
--------------+---------------------+----------
12458         |  481181880922       |   X    
12458         |  481181880924       |   X    
12458         |  481181880926       |   X    
30689         |  485481881862       |   X    
30699         |  485481881861       |   X       
11449         |  483981889371       |   X    
44775         |  480081880924       |   X    
44775         |  480081880922       |   X 
44775         |  480081880923       |   X    
44775         |  480081880925       |   X
```

My expected result: it should only show items with 3 or more results:

```
ITEM          | BARCODE             | TYPE  
--------------+---------------------+---------
12458         |  481181880922       |   X    
12458         |  481181880924       |   X    
12458         |  481181880926       |   X       
44775         |  480081880924       |   X    
44775         |  480081880922       |   X 
44775         |  480081880923       |   X    
44775         |  480081880925       |   X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT INUMBR AS ITEM, IUPC AS BARCODE, IUPCCD AS TYPE,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY INUMBR) ITEM_CNT
    FROM [DWSTAGE].[INVUPC] 
    WHERE iupccd = 'X'
)

SELECT ITEM, BARCODE, TYPE
FROM cte
WHERE ITEM_CNT >= 3
ORDER BY BARCODE;
```

Comment: Hi, theres an error with this line : COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM) ITEM_CNT  
Error message: invalid column name ITEM

Comment: @EfrenCaballes Sorry, typo, it should be `PARTITION BY INUMBR`, because the alias `ITEM` doesn't exist yet at that level of the query.  It should work now.